# Python: Decomposing two time stamps into individual hours

Tags: python-2.7

Want to figure out if there is an efficient way to break the gap between two timestamps into individual hours.

Suppose I have an observation: `start=12:00`, `end=18:00`. I would like to convert this one observation into 6 observations one for each hour in between. `I.e. 12, 13, 14...,18.`

I already know how to do this with if/else, loop based answers, **I am looking for a more efficient implementation if possible**.

Comment: Then, better share what already you have ... so that viewers can suggest you

Answer (score 0):

If by "efficient" you mean "with minimal code", you could try using `datetime.time` with a range:

```
>>> from datetime import time
>>> [time(hour=h) for h in range(12, 19)]
[datetime.time(12, 0), datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(14, 0),
datetime.time(15, 0), datetime.time(16, 0), datetime.time(17, 0),
datetime.time(18, 0)]
```

Since time takes hour as its first positional argument, you could even make it slightly shorter with map:

```
>>> map(time, range(12, 19)]
```

If you are starting from `datetime` objects, you could use timedelta to make a range between them:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> before = datetime(2018,2,1,12,0)
>>> after = datetime(2018,2,1,18,0)
>>> seconds = int((after - before).total_seconds())
>>> [before + timedelta(seconds=s) for s in range(0, seconds, 3600)]
[datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 13, 0),
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 15, 0),
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 17, 0)]
```